# Apple Watch App : Specific function call from iPhone in handleWatchKitExtensionRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-watch

When a request comes from watch kit extension for data, can we call any function from `iphone` app into `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` method and pass the data in reply`(@{});?`like this  If we can call, please let me know the procedure for doing the same.

Please help me in achieving this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have made this stuff in my app. (But not passed reply)

In Watch Kit Extention
On One button Tap event i have write below code

```
    NSMutableDictionary *callDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [callDict setObject:@"SendPushLocation" forKey:@"type"];
    [callDict setObject:contactDetail forKey:@"data"];

    [WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:callDict reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {


    }];
```

And After that in appDelegate.m
Added this code to achieve what you want.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply {

    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ContactListTableViewController *contactTableVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContactListTableVC"];
    [contactTableVC viewDidLoadCopy];
    if ([userInfo[@"type"] isEqualToString:@"SendPush"]) {

        [contactTableVC sendPushFromWatchKit:userInfo[@"data"] withSendLocation:NO];

    } else if([userInfo[@"type"] isEqualToString:@"SendPushLocation"]) {

        [contactTableVC sendPushFromWatchKit:userInfo[@"data"] withSendLocation:YES];

    } else if([userInfo[@"type"] isEqualToString:@"LocalNotification"]) {

        [contactTableVC scheduleLocalNotification:userInfo[@"data"]];

    } else if([userInfo[@"type"] isEqualToString:@"ReScheduleLocalNotification"]) {

        [contactTableVC reScheduleLocalNotification:userInfo[@"data"]];

    }
}
```

I don't need reply so i have not tried for that.